# How to return all documents that have a field that contains a given string

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I have a question, I'm creating a react app, using Node and MongoDB as back-end, and I'm trying to get all the documents from a collection, that have a field that contains a given string.
This is how I tried it, when I leave the params empty, it does return all the movies, but when I'm typing something after the "/" it gives me an error
In my case I'm trying to get all the movies, whose title contains some letters, to implement a search component

```
router.get("/:query", async (req, res) => {
    let listTemp = [];
    listTemp = await Movie.find({$contains:{"title": {$regex : req.params.query}}});
    try {
        ids = []
        listTemp.forEach(elem => {
          ids.push(elem._id);
        })
        res.status(200).json(ids);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
}
);
```

Comment: show what is req.params.query by console.log

Comment: Please post the error also. Also I suggest you to use query. `req.query.search` your url will be `/?search=something` and `router.get("/")...`

Comment: It's not an error, I didn't make the request how it should, but now, doesn't matter what query I give, It returns all the movies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

`Movie.find({title: { $regex: '.*' + req.params.query + '.*' } });`